# C# Dynamic MenuStrip (without touching form)

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, menustrip

Is it possible to dynamically create a MenuStrip without adding the instance via the form?

I have done..

```
//Create menu
MenuStrip menu = new MenuStrip();
menu.name = "MainMenu";

// Create a Menu Item
ToolStripMenuItem file = new ToolStripMenuItem("File");

//Add item to Menu
menu.Items.Add(file);

//Click event
file.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.FileItemClick);

private void FileItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("File clicked");
}
```

I know I have to add it to the form with something like this..

```
this.MainMenuStrip = menu;
Controls.Add(menu);
```

but without an instance dragged onto the form already, the above isn't possible.
Is there a way to 100% dynamically create a MenuStrip? Also, SubMenus?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, all controls that you drag to the form are generated into code by the designer. To see exactly what code you need, just drag a `MenuStrip` control onto the form and then open the designer file (in Notepad) and copy & paste the code from there. If your form is called `Form1.cs` then your designer file is `Form1.designer.cs`.

The designer file is all generated code that creates and initializes all controls on your form to the values you select in the `Properties` tool window when you visually desing your form.